Use Safe as proposer or executor in TimelockController
I want to use Safe to sig transactions to propose or execute transactions in my TimelockController. As far as I know Safe uses proxy contracts. Is it possible to use Safe for such case and if so how I can get address to assign roles to it?

I think it's possible.
After you create your gnoisafe, don't it show up the address?

It should be possible. Have you tried by simply adding the address of your Safe as a proposer and/or executor?
Please let me know! Thanks in advance, Louis

Hi Louis! Yes, I understand general principle and I can add address of my safe as a proposer role. But I'm worried about proxy pattern. As far as I know Safe implements it and will address change when contract get updated? How it will effect my contract?

Safe uses the proxy pattern but once your safe is deployed it will stay at the same address, even if functionality changes
